# Removing elements from an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void removeElement( String candidate ) {
    
    // hitta elementet som ska tas bort och placera det sist i arrayen
    for( int i = 0; i < carRegister.length; i++ ) {
        String s = carRegister[i];
        if( s.equals( candidate ) ) {
            // byt plats med sista elementet
            String temp = carRegister[carRegister.length-1];
            carRegister[carRegister.length-1] = s;
            carRegister[i] = temp;
        }           
    }
    
    
    // Ta bort elementet genom att kopiera över alla utom sista elementet till en ny array
    String[] tempArray = new String[carRegister.length-1];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < carRegister.length-1; i++ ) {
        tempArray[i] = carRegister[i];
    }
    
    // den nya arrayen tilldelas arrayen carRegister
    carRegister = tempArray;
}
```

My problem with the code is that I do not find a way to prevent the copying from the second for loop if the user input (candidate) does not match any of the elements in the array. As you can see it removes Mazda even though the input is "Tesla". I don't know how to stop it from removing the last element in the array in this case.[image]

Comment: Why does `Mazda` get moved to the first index? What's the point of storing `Volvo` at the end before truncating? Why don't you make the copy inside the `if`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the layout that I am meant to use. The execution program wants it that way. But to answer your first question, Mazda gets moved to the first index because it swaps places with Volvo. So Volvo gets moved to the last index and Mazda the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a variable to store whether you have found the candidate or not? Then, if the variable says that you have not found it, the second loop can be avoided. For example,

```
   ...
   boolean foundCandidate = false; // initialized to "did not find it" 
   for( int i = 0; i < carRegister.length; i++ ) {
       String s = carRegister[i];
       if( s.equals( candidate ) ) {
          // changed if found
          foundCandidate = true;
          ...

   // now, you can avoid this loop (and modifying carRegister) if it is not necessary
   if( foundCanidate) {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: Implemented your code and it still has the same issue, it still copies out Mazda.

Comment: No it doesn't: https://ideone.com/12LK87

Comment: Hmm terrible sorry about that, I must have missed something because I implemented it the way you did now and it did not work, maybe I missed a Big letter or something. Anyhow many thanks to you tucuxi! It works fine now..